# How to run code example chat in chapter 2 ebook Java Message Service?

Tags: java, jms

How can run chat.class in chapter 2 ebook Java Message Service?

[code here](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jms_ch2/?page=2)

I can't run main method Although i add javax.jms still can't run

```
/* Run the Chat client */
    public static void main(String [] args){
        try{
            if(args.length!=3)
                System.out.println("Topic or username missing");

            // args[0]=topicName; args[1]=username; args[2]=password
            Chat chat = new Chat(args[0],args[1],args[2]);

            // read from command line
            BufferedReader commandLine = new
              java.io.BufferedReader(new
                                     InputStreamReader(System.in));

            // loop until the word "exit" is typed
            while(true){
                String s = commandLine.readLine();
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
                    chat.close(); // close down connection
                    System.exit(0);// exit program
                }else
                    chat.writeMessage(s);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

error

```
Topic or username missing
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at chap2.chat.Chat.main(Chat.java:97)
```

Comment: Maybe by trying? Hint: most books continue explicit instructions on how to run their example code.

Comment: Individual xxxxx.class files are not necessarily "runnable". The way Java works is that you tell the JVM where an application's entry point is (which will be contained within *a* xxxxx.class file, also a set of source may contain multiple entry points). The entry point is defined my a `main()` method. There are many places that show how to do this: http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html

Comment: As to your particular `chat.class` file... I don't know. Does it contain a `main()` method... does it require arguments... who knows? (Tip: the book knows)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, in its current form, this is not a good question. I suggest you edit the chat.class into your question (use the "edit" link below your post for this). Then add how you are trying to run the class, and what happens. Is there an error message?

Comment: apologize! i will fix!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're quite new to Java.
First, notice that the message you get ("Topic or username missing") comes from the code itself, so the code *is* running.

Look where this comes from: it is printed because `args.length` is not equal to 3. When you run a Java class from the command line, the parameters are passed into the `args` array. So, you should have provided enough parameters.

That should solve the direct problem. Below the line, I'd like to explain a bit more.

---

The error message

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>       at chap2.chat.Chat.main(Chat.java:97)

is quite clear: it goes wrong in line 97 of Chat.java. In the `main` method.
If you see this, you should look in your code for that line (most IDE's tell you the line number, if you know where to look).

When you post a question here on SO (or anywhere), and have a stack trace 
with a line number, it is good practice to point out which line the line number refers to. That helps those who read your question to better understand the problem.

An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means that you have an array index that is pointing outside the array.
I have a hunch that the line in question is this one:

```
Chat chat = new Chat(args[0],args[1],args[2]);
```

In this case the index value is 0, as we can see in the error message. It may be a bit confusing for a beginner, but `args[0]` is the *first* value in your array. (`args[1]` is the second, `args[2]` the third, and so on).

So if 0 is already out of the bounds of the array... that means your array doesn't even have a first value. It has 0 values.

The error then results from Java trying to read the first element of an array that has 0 elements. The solution is to:

- either make sure that the array has enough values
- or provide an error message and stop executing that part of the code.

This example is a bit sloppy because it did provide an error message, but then continued to execute the code until it broke.